# Calling a function when $.each is done

Tags: javascript

If I run the showFriends() function in the Chrome console, I can see the data. However in the code, I'm calling showFriends() after the $.each function -- it fails because it seems to be running asynchrounously.

I've tried chaining .promise().done(showFriends(); after the $.each function but that also failed.

Any ideas?

```
var myApp = {};
myApp.fbFriends = [];

function showFriends() {
  console.log(myApp.fbFriends);
}

function getFriends() {

  FB.api('/me/friends?fields=birthday', function(response) {
    var friendsBirthdays = response.data;
    friendsIdArray = friendsBirthdays.map(function(user) { return user.id });
    createFriendsArray(friendsIdArray);
  });

  function createFriendsArray(friendsIdArray) {

    $.each(friendsIdArray, function(index, value) {
      FB.api(value.toString(), function(response) {
        myApp.fbFriends.push(response);
      });
    });
    showFriends();
  }
}
```

Comment: `each` is not async, that `FB.api` call however is probably async.

Comment: you can also use the `done()` jquery

Comment: @rockStar: How should that go? You need a promise before you can call `.done`.

Comment: thatwould go `.promise().done(//your function here);`

Comment: @rockStar: And where do you call `.promise` on? Also, did you read what the OP wrote? *"I've tried chaining .promise().done [...] after the $.each function but that also failed"* If you can provide a complete example, you convince me.

Comment: Ops my bad i just read the first para then go straight the code. :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing else, you can compare the length of friendIdArray and myApp.fbFriends after each push, and if they are the same and bigger than zero, run `showFriends()`. That will ensure the friends are shown after the last iteration.

So something like this:

```
$.each(friendsIdArray, function(index, value) {
  FB.api(value.toString(), function(response) {
    myApp.fbFriends.push(response);
    if (myApp.fbFriends.length == friendsIdArray.length)
      showFriends();
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 I wanted to suggest deferred objects/promises, but this has much less overhead. Promises could still be nice to decouple the code later on.

Comment: Yes, for something as simple as this, comparing lengths is okay... but for anything complex, I'd go with promises. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Ps.: Actually what I'll be doing is passing the response like showFriends(response) so I can display friends as they are available.